# Weak Instrument - Stock and Yogo

Tags: instrumental-variable

I have  the following structural equations where $G,Z$ are endogenous and $X,Y$ are exogenous

$$ G_d=B_0+B_1Z+B_2X+u_1\\
G_s=a_0 +a_1Z+a_2Y+u_2 \\
G_d=G_s
$$

Now, I would like to perform 2SLS, thus, I started off by obtaining the reduced-form equations

$$
Z=c_1+c_2Y+c_3X+v_1 \\
G=d_1+d_2Y+d_3X+v_2
$$

Now how do I proceed to test for weak instruments? should I consider the overall F test for the two reduced form equations? or consider the individual t statistics?

Comment: There's no error term in the reduced form equations? Which equation are you estimating? Which variable is being instrumented?

Comment: I just added the error term, I am following 2SLS estimation, whereby I would like to use an instrumental variable instead of Z.

Comment: Z is the only endogenous variable on the RHS of the equation which will cause it be correlated with the error term leading to simulatenous equation bias. As a result, I need an instrument variable for Z which is usually the fitted values obtained from the reduced form equation. My problem is how to test whether the instrument variables are weak or not